# Forge 1.16.5 get attack damage of an item

Tags: minecraft-forge

I am trying to get the attack damage of the item in the players offhand. So far I have this `mc.player.inventory.offhand.get(0)` in my world ticking event (mc is the instance of minecraft). But the item does not seem to have any attack damage attribute. Is there some other way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and It took me a while to figure this out. Here's my solution.

Note: I'm using fabric, but this should still work in a similar way with forge.

```
ItemStack handItem = minecraftClient.player.getMainHandStack();

// get the damage of the item in the players main hand (does not include player base damage)
String itemDamageStr = handItem.getAttributeModifiers(EquipmentSlot.MAINHAND).get(EntityAttributes.GENERIC_ATTACK_DAMAGE).toString().replaceFirst(".*?amount=([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+).*", "$1");
Double itemDamage = 0.0;
if(itemDamageStr.matches("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")){
  itemDamage = Double.parseDouble(itemDamageStr);
}

// get the players damage
Double playerDamage = minecraftClient.player.getAttributes().getValue(EntityAttributes.GENERIC_ATTACK_DAMAGE);

float totalDamage = (float) (itemDamage + playerDamage);
```

Also, just in case someone finds this helpful, when I was trying to get the player to damage an entity, I had to grab the entity from the server world in order to do anything to it from the client.

```
ServerWorld serverWorld = minecraftClient.getServer().getWorld(minecraftClient.world.getRegistryKey());

Entity entity = minecraftClient.targetedEntity;

Entity serverEntity = serverWorld.getEntity(entity.getUuid());
```